# Why Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 dose not support TimeOnly Data type?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, timespan

I have an entity with at least 14 Time-only fields.  After some research it seems that CRM does not support the timespan data type at all.  I have to use DateTime with the date part hidden or use a string field to display and store time values.

Why does MS Dynamics CRM not support the timespan datatype?

Answer (score 0):

It is by design. In case you want that type to be supported you can leave your suggestion at [Connect portal](http://connect.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to know if any consideration exists for this limitation?

Comment: Why not just use a string field as you mention in your question?

Comment: In my scenario I have to create SDK level entities, according to these _time_ fields. By string format, I have to cast to **Time Span** in every creation.

Answer (score 0):

The MSCRM Database does not hold 'time' fields but datetime, you could hold timespan as Int\decimal if you are just going to use the value in your code.